# Access Pointer To Structure Of Same Type?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, structure

I'm trying to build a linked list and need a pointer, pointing to the next element - also storing data and a pointer to the next element of the list.

Would this be the right approach and how would I access this type of pointer via main() ?

```
struct Data {

    int data = 1;
};
typedef struct Data Data;

struct Node {

    Data d;
    struct Node *dir_next; 
};
typedef struct Node Node;
```

Comment: Note that you can also either merge the typedef into the struct definition (very common), or do the typedef before the struct definition.

Comment: You don't need to `typedef struct` in C++

Comment: What you have looks perfectly reasonable to me, but I would add a `linkedlist` class to contain and manage the nodes for you. This often makes the job much simpler.

Comment: C++ has built-in standard linked list implementations : `std::list` (double linked) and `std::forward_list` (single linked). You would do well to learn them instead of write your own implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is right, but there are some unnecessary things in your code.

```
struct Data {

    int data = 1;
};

struct Node {

    Data d;
    Node *dir_next; 
};
```

This is all you need and this is the standard way to create linked lists.

To access the list elements you can do:

```
Node current;
//build your list here
Node next = *(current.dir_next);
```

or using pointers

```
Node* current;
//build your list here
Node* next = current->dir_next;
```